# A more efficient proof of associativity law for a given binary operation

Tags: alternative-proof, binary-operations, associativity

Consider the following definition for a binary operation on the real numbers.

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Define the operation $*$ as follows.
>
> $$x * y = \begin{cases} x, & \text{if} & x \geq y \\ y, & \text{if} & x \leq y. \end{cases}$$

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers. Prove that $(a * b) * c = a * (b * c).$

As a first attempt, we could use the *Trichotomy Law* and treat each case separately. Although, when we think of the number of cases that we have to consider, we easily give up on this approach. (Since we would have to consider about $13$ cases, if I’m not wrong.)

*I am seeking now an alternative (and possibly, a more efficient) proof for this result.*

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?

I also tried to rely on the meaning of this operation, i.e., looking at the definition, we easily conclude that $a * b$ gives the greatest number, if $a \neq b$, or just $a$ or $b$ in the case $a = b.$ But this not seems very formal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, this is precisely the [maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element) operation $\text{max}(x, y)$, and $\text{max}$ is associative because

$$\text{max}(\text{max}(x, y), z) = \text{max}(x, \text{max}(y, z)) = \text{max}(x, y, z)$$

is just the maximum among the three numbers $x, y, z$; no casework is necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Each of those expressions in fact represents the maximum among the three numbers. This will suffice to note that the $\max$ operation is associative, right?

Comment: Yes. This is an instance of a much more general pattern; for example tensor products of vector spaces are associative (up to isomorphism) for a very similar reason (that both parenthesizations represent a common meaningful third object, the triple tensor product), although that example is more complicated to understand.

Comment: The supremum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum), which generalizes the maximum to infinite sets of real numbers, is even "infinitely associative" in the sense that if $S_i$ is any collection of subsets of the real numbers, then $\sup(\sup(S_i)) = \sup(\cup S_i)$. Here we need to allow $\infty$ as a possible value.

Comment: Oh I see! That makes sense! Thank you so much for clarifying:)

Comment: Ah, here's a simpler example that's also similar: the $\gcd$ (greatest common divisor) is also associative because $\gcd(\gcd(a, b), c) = \gcd(a, \gcd(b, c)) = \gcd(a, b, c)$ is the greatest common divisor of three numbers. Describing the maximum as the "least upper bound" may make the analogy clearer. All of this generalizes to joins and meets in arbitrary posets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset